# if statement to determine which route is used in jinja template, flask

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2

I have two views which uses one template.

```
@users.route("/one")
@login_required
def one(username):
     return render_template('follower.html')
```

and

```
@users.route("/two")
@login_required
def two(username):
     return render_template('follower.html')
```

in the jinja template ( follower.html ), I am trying to execute a program if route one is used like this:

```
{% if url_for('users.one')  %}
    execute program
{% endif %}
```

but it seems I am doing it wrongly. Please what is the correct way of determine which route is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply, in your template file, write a condition to check if `request.endpoint` equals the function name for the desired route, which in this case would be `one`, as seen in this example:

```
{% if request.endpoint == 'one'  %}
    execute program
{% endif %}
```

In this way, you will not make any changes to your route functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two functions with the same name - they are both named `two`.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish this is to pass in a flag. E.g.,

```
@users.route("/one")
@login_required
def one(username):
    return render_template('follower.html', one=True)
```

then check for it in the template

```
{% if one %}
    execute program
{% endif %}
```

from `two()` you'd padd `one=False`.